# I cannot define the class to the Scriptableobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created ScriptableObject but unfortunately I cannot assign the class which i created into it. What should I do?

Codes

[image: Codes]

CardScript

[image: CardScript]

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried to do something like this but now i cannot add script to the card gameobject

```c#
public class CardDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Card card;
    public TextMeshProUGUI nameText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI descText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI APText;
    
    public Image cardbackground;
    public Image artworkImage;
    public Image maskImage;
    
    public void SetProperties()
    {
        ///To take a data from localizer. Shalalalaaaa.
        var NameText = LocalizationSettings.StringDatabase.GetLocalizedStringAsync("CARD_NAME", card.Key);
        NameText.Completed += (op) => nameText.text = op.Result;
    
        var DescText = LocalizationSettings.StringDatabase.GetLocalizedStringAsync("CARD_DESC", card.Key);
        DescText.Completed += (op) => descText.text = op.Result;
    
        APText.text = card.ActionPoint.ToString();
    
        if (card.Artwork != null)
            artworkImage.sprite = card.Artwork;
    
        cardbackground.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Items/Card/CardBackgrounds/Card_"+card.rarity);
        maskImage.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Items/Card/CardMasks/"+ card.rarity +"_Mask");
        foreach (CardScript a in Resources.LoadAll<CardScript>("Items/Card/CardScripts"))
        {
            Debug.Log(a.name);
        }

        if(Resources.Load<CardScript>("Items/Card/CardScripts/"+card.Key) != null)
            gameObject.AddComponent(Resources.Load("Items/Card/CardScripts/"+card.Key).GetType());
    }
}
```

Comment: i've crying to create a card game. Im planning to when i will going to call a function from  card. i'll going to access it to Scriptableobject and call a function which script is inside of ScriptableObject.

Comment: It would be helpful to see more code, where is cardScript defined?

Comment: the cardscript is defined in resources and already there is nothing in cardScript. I edited the post and added the screenshot of the cardscript

Comment: Please don't add images of code! Rather copy paste your code as text and format it using the `{ }` button!

Comment: Yoi can't add Scene references to assets. Only the other way round and references between assets are allowed.

Comment: I've updated the post. @derHugo